# Encrypting RSA Public Key in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption

I have been tasked with encrypting all of the passwords in our application.yml file. I've been using https://medium.com/@sun30nil/how-to-secure-secrets-and-passwords-in-springboot-90c952961d9 and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt to guide me. This is going fine until I reached the following lines in my application.yml

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue:
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          RAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGE
          AREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISE
          RABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINF
          RAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZ
          INFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTR
          AZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALO
          OTRAZZIN
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

How do I encrypt these types of keys with the command:

```
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.2/jasypt-1.9.2.jar org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input=”Topsecret@123" password=dev-env-secret algorithm=PBEWITHMD5ANDDES
```

and then place inside of ENC() in my application.yml?

Googled several phrases with no luck.

Comment: The rather obvious question is: why would you  want to encrypt a *public* key?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, because my boss told me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I finally used was simply to place ENC() on each line of the key. So, for example,

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue:
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          @ENC(RAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGE)
          @ENC(AREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISE)
          @ENC(RABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINF)
          @ENC(RAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZ)
          @ENC(INFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTR)
          @ENC(AZZINFRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALOOTRAZZINMISERABLELONGEAREDGALO)
          @ENC(OTRAZZIN)
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```